# Drawing Two rects around two Surfaces in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, draw, surface, rect

I am trying two draw two surfaces, one on top of the other, each with a border around it. Both the top surface (topSurf) and the bottom surface (botSurf) appear on the screen.

When I attempt to draw a border around each surface with the pygame.draw.rect command, the rect on the top surface appears, but the rect on the bottom surface does not.

Why does this happen?

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))

#top surface
topRect = pygame.Rect(0,0,600,500)
topSurf = pygame.Surface((600,500))
topSurf = topSurf.convert()
topSurf.fill(BLUE)

#bottom surface
botSurf = pygame.Surface((600,100))
botRect = pygame.Rect(0,500,600,100)
botSurf = botSurf.convert()
botSurf.fill(GREEN)

#rectangle
pygame.draw.rect(topSurf,RED,topRect,10)
pygame.draw.rect(botSurf,WHITE,botRect,10)



### main game loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(topSurf,topRect)
    screen.blit(botSurf,botRect)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T84Ta.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `botRect`'s coordinates to draw the white rect and that means you're drawing it at the surfaces local coordinates `(0, 500)`, outside of the area of the `botSurf`. You have to draw the rect at `(0, 0)` first and then move the rect afterwards if you also want to use it as the blit position of the surface.

```
botSurf = pygame.Surface((600,100))
botSurf.fill(GREEN)
botRect = pygame.Rect(0,0,600,100)
pygame.draw.rect(botSurf,WHITE,botRect,10)
botRect.y = 500
```